# Add item to a specific column in ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I have an `increment system` and I want when `onClick` to save value from `DialogAlert` in a column in `ListView Adapter`.

**Here is my `Adapter`:**

```
public class VanzatorProduseList extends ArrayAdapter<VanzatorProduse> {

private Activity context;
private SparseBooleanArray selectedListItemsIds;
private List<VanzatorProduse> vanzatorProduseList;


public VanzatorProduseList(Activity context, List<VanzatorProduse> vanzatorProduseList){
    super(context, R.layout.list_produse_vanzator, vanzatorProduseList);
    this.context = context;
    selectedListItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.vanzatorProduseList = vanzatorProduseList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_produse_vanzator, null, true);

    TextView textViewProdus1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewProdus1);
    TextView textViewPret1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPret1);
    final TextView textViewCantitate1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCantitate1);

    final VanzatorProduse vanzatorProduse = vanzatorProduseList.get(position);

    textViewProdus1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getProdus());
    textViewPret1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getPret());


    textViewCantitate1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_alert);
            dialog.setTitle("Alege Canitatea");

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            final Button dialogBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
            final ElegantNumberButton elegantNumberButton = (ElegantNumberButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.elegantNumberButton);

            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                String num = elegantNumberButton.getNumber();
                vanzatorProduseList.add(num);
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    return listViewItem;
}
```

**Here is what I tried but I got an error and no idea what to do next :**

```
 String num = elegantNumberButton.getNumber();
                vanzatorProduseList.add(num);
```

**Error:**

```
'add(com.dev.darius.neglije.Vanzator.ListaProduse.VanzatorProduse)' in 'java.util.List' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'
```

Here I'm stuck I want to display in `TextView` called `textViewCantitate1`.

Hope you understand.

Comment: You are trying to add a `String` in a `List` of `VanzatorProduse` elements. It can't work, you have to add a `VanzatorProduse` object to that list

Answer (score 1):

As stated in earlier answers by @jibrahim:

> You are trying to add String type into List vanzatorProduseList. You can add only VanzatorProduse type into vanzatorProduseList list. So, the cause of the problem is:

```
String num = elegantNumberButton.getNumber();
vanzatorProduseList.add(num);
```

> You need to do something like this **Create Object of your Custom class and assign value to that**:

```
 String num = elegantNumberButton.getNumber();
    VanzatorProduse numVanProObject = new VanzatorProduse();
    numVanProObject .setNumber(num );
    vanzatorProduseList.add(numVanProObject );
```

> But your custom call should have method to cater this type issue

**Edit: Do not forget to call notifyDataSetChanged() method to refresh the list**

Comment: You should also call notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the list view.

Comment: sorry I'm new to java.. but from here how can i display the result in my TetxView(textviewcantitate) ? like these textviews (textviewprodust, textviewpret)

Comment: you can do this simply in on close `textviewcantitate.setText(String.valueOf(num))`;
But if I am not wrong you are asking for updating the list , this can be easily done by calling `yourListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add `String` type into `List<VanzatorProduse> vanzatorProduseList`. You can add only `VanzatorProduse` type into `vanzatorProduseList` list. So, the cause of the problem is:

```
String num = elegantNumberButton.getNumber();
vanzatorProduseList.add(num);
```

In your code you have following lines:

```
final VanzatorProduse vanzatorProduse = vanzatorProduseList.get(position);

textViewProdus1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getProdus());
textViewPret1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getPret());
```

So, might be you add `num` value into `vanzatorProduse.setProdus(num)` or any **other appropriate field** and then add it into the list:

```
vanzatorProduseList.add(vanzatorProduse);
```

Comment: You cannot just add it. You have to put this info inside a `VanzatorProduse` object and add this object to the list

Comment: @pleft sure and @Clau should know where exactly to assign the `num` value into `VanzatorProduse`

Answer (score 0):

```
VanzatorProduse producse = new VanzatorProduse();
producse.setProdus("add value here")
vanzatorProduseList.add(producse);
```